# TypeScript won't select the right override

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-tsx

I just created a dynamic component what should look like the next:

/*
   Should inherit all InputComponent properties.
   DefaultComponent should be the default component props value.
*/

```
<DynamicComponent component={InputComponent} />
```

My current implementation looks like the next:

```
type DefaultProps = { defaultProp: string }
type InputProps = { onChange: () => void }
type DynamicType<P> = DynamicProps & { component: ReactType<P> } & P

export default function DynamicComponent(props: DynamicProps & { component?: DefaultComponent } & DefaultComponentProps): ReactElement<DefaultComponentProps>
export default function DynamicComponent<P>(props: DynamicType<P>): ReactElement<P> {
    const { style: overrideStyle, component } = props
    const { style } = getStyle(props)
    const mergedStyle = { ...style, ...overrideStyle }
    return React.createElement(component, { ...props, style: mergedStyle })
};

DynamicComponent.defaultProps = { component: DefaultComponent }
```

So I would expect the next to happen:

1.) When the component is not defined I expect the 1st override (the one with the default)

```
<DynamicComponent defaultProps='itsTotallyValid' /> // valid
```

2.) When the component is defined I expect to inherit it's properties

```
<DynamicComponent component={InputComponent} onChange={() =>{}} /> // valid
```

For some reason the 2nd situation never happens, and it's always selects the first one. Is there a way to be more strict, so I can force the 2nd situation to be possible?

## Update

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-architecture-zx60y

Comment: Why do you have two function declarations?

Comment: Yes, that a way I wanted to go forward,  but it's would be nicer if I could solve this with one component. (Else I can go with DefaultDynamicComponent + DynamicComponent)

Comment: Typescript supports default values for generics. You can provide with `<P = DefaultComponent>`

Comment: The thing is, as my generics kinda comes from infer the props types and inheriting from it, I can't really add a default to the Generics:

type DynamicType<P> = DynamicProps & { component: ReactType<P> } & P

Comment: Can you post, `DynamicProps` ?

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the concern in the comments about the default generic type blocking type inference, that is not the case, the following minimal example demonstrates type inference working on type `T` which has a default of `string`,

```
function Bar<T = string>(props: { component: T }) : T {
  return props.component
}

Bar({ component : 'string' })
Bar({ component : 5 }) // <-- Type inferred to be number
```

Comment: Hmm yeah so it's not because of the infer type it's not working :/
One sec

Comment: Just made an example.

Comment: That's strange, but you have the important case, the explicit component working for now. I'll keep looking into this

Comment: Nice one, if you find anything let me know please :). This always annoyed me... :D